# How many ways to divide 11 people into 3 groups of 3 and one group of 2?

Tags: permutations

How many ways are there to divide 11 people into 3 groups of 3 and one group of 2?
The right answer is 15400 but I can't get it

Answer (score 2):

$$\binom{11}{3}\cdot \binom{8}{3} \cdot \binom{5}{3} \over 3!$$
We divide by $3!$ because we dont care about order in group

Comment: You can use the \binom $\binom{n}{p}$ instead of the old notation $C_n^p$.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine how many ways can you arrange 11 people in a row?

That is $11!$  Then let the first 3 be group 1, the next 3 be group 2, the next 3 be group 3 and the last 2 be group 4.

There are $3!$ ways to arrange each group of 3 and $2!$ ways to arrange the group of 2.  As well as $3!$ ways to arrange the 3 groups of 3.  So...
$$\frac{11!}{3!\times3!\times3!\times2!\times3!}$$

EDIT: Volodymyr Fomenko's answer is equivalent and makes more sense than mine.
$$\frac{11\times10\times9}{3!}\frac{8\times7\times6}{3!}\frac{5\times4\times3}{3!}\frac{2\times1}{2!}\frac{1}{3!}$$